# how can i create a c3 graph with dynamic values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, c3.js

Im trying to make a c3 chart in my vuejs project using the vue-c3 reusable component. the problem is in the data.column option i didnt know exactly how to pass dynamic values to it here's what i've done for now

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import VueC3 from "vue-c3";
import axios from "v/vue-http";

@Component<SalesChart>({
  name: "SalesChart",
  components: { VueC3 },
  data() {
    return {
      handler: new Vue()
    };
  }
})
export default class SalesChart extends Vue {
  salesData: object;

  get salesValues(): array {
    return Object.values(this.salesData);
  }
  get options(): object {
    return {
      data: {
        columns: [['sales', 175,45,98,76]],
        type: "area-spline"
      },
      tooltip: {
        format: {
          title() {
            return `test title`;
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  mounted(): void {
    this.handler.$emit("init", this.options);
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
    axios
      .get("/sales_analytics/30")
      .then(response => {
        this.salesData = response.data.data;
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

so when i do

`data: {
            columns: [['sales', 175,45,98,76]],
            type: "area-spline"
          },`

the graph renders correctly but when i try to pass the salesValues `columns: [this.salesValues]`  i get an error telling : `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"` i dont know what i could be doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to point to:

```
salesData: object; // null or undefined

get salesValues(): array {
  return Object.values(this.salesData); // throws
}
```

possible fix:

```
  get salesValues(): array {
    return (this.salesData && Object.values(this.salesData))
    || ['sales', 175,45,98,76];
  }
  get options(): object {
    return {
      data: {
        columns: [this.salesValue],
        type: "area-spline"
      },
      tooltip: {
        format: {
          title() {
            return `test title`;
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
```